# My Snake plant never seems to grow

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

I've had this plant for over 5 years and it has been at the same length it's at now. I've tried feeding it with miracle grow pebbles and liquid, and it still doesn't grow. Whats wrong with my plant and is their anything I can do other than feed it to make it grow?

[image: plant1]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your plant is Sansevieria trifasciata - S.  trifasciata laurentii is similar, but has yellow bands at the edges of the leaves, and that variety can reach up to three feet, but usually makes 1.5 feet. Your plant, though, is smaller and will not make the same height as S. laurentii - even so, it does look rather etiolated, so if it's in a situation where it doesn't get much daylight, it would do better if you move it to a brighter spot - but it still won't get so tall as S. laurentii.

http://m.wikihow.com/Care-for-a-Sansevieria-or-Snake-Plant